# R pairwise operations

Tags: r

I have a data frame and would like to perform some specific operations on it.

```
dat <- data.frame(Name = LETTERS[1:3],
                  Val1 = rnorm(3),
                  Val2 = rnorm(3))

# > dat
#   Name      Val1       Val2
# 1    A -1.055050  0.4499766
# 2    B  0.414994 -0.5999369
# 3    C -1.311374 -0.3967634
```

I would like to do the following:

1. Pair-wise divide Val1 across the Names, e.g.

```
AB1 <- dat[dat$Name == "A", "Val1"] / dat[dat$Name == "B", "Val1"]
AC1 <- dat[dat$Name == "A", "Val1"] / dat[dat$Name == "C", "Val1"]  
BC1 <- dat[dat$Name == "B", "Val1"] / dat[dat$Name == "C", "Val1"]
```

2. Pair-wise divide Val2 across the Names, e.g.

```
AB2 <- dat[dat$Name == "A", "Val2"] / dat[dat$Name == "B", "Val2"]
AC2 <- dat[dat$Name == "A", "Val2"] / dat[dat$Name == "C", "Val2"]  
BC2 <- dat[dat$Name == "B", "Val2"] / dat[dat$Name == "C", "Val2"]
```

3. Subtract 2 from 1, e.g.

```
AB3 <- AB1 - AB2
AC3 <- AC1 - AC2
BC3 <- BC1 - BC2
```

The above works fine but I'd like to implement this in a smarter and scalable way (e.g many more Names and Vals), as well as storing the output in a data.frame where it is easier to programmatically extract values.

Finally, an even better solution would do this for the following data

```
dat2 <- data.frame(Region = rep(LETTERS[24:26], each=3),
                   Name = rep(LETTERS[1:3], 3),
                   Val1 = rep(rnorm(3), 3),
                   Val2 = rep(rnorm(3), 3))
> dat2
#   Region Name      Val1       Val2
# 1      X    A 2.1098629  0.5779044
# 2      X    B 0.5937334  0.1410554
# 3      X    C 0.2819461 -1.1769578
# 4      Y    A 2.1098629  0.5779044
# 5      Y    B 0.5937334  0.1410554
# 6      Y    C 0.2819461 -1.1769578
# 7      Z    A 2.1098629  0.5779044
# 8      Z    B 0.5937334  0.1410554
# 9      Z    C 0.2819461 -1.1769578
```

Where the operations are the same as above but grouped by Region, so the output would be something like

```
> output
#   Region  AB3   AC3   BC3
# 1      X    ?     ?     ?
# 2      Y    ?     ?     ?
# 3      Z    ?     ?     ?
```

where the `?` are the actual results.

Comment: There are various ways to do this, but a reasonably efficient one is to iterate across a `combn` call, e.g. `sapply(combn(nrow(dat), 2, simplify = FALSE), function(i){dat[i[1], 'Val1'] / dat[i[2], 'Val1']})`

Comment: @alistaire your comment is good for doing one of the points, and could be extended to do all 3 points using `sapply(combn(nrow(dat), 2, simplify = FALSE), function(i){dat[i[1], 'Val1'] / dat[i[2], 'Val1'] - dat[i[1], 'Val2'] / dat[i[2], 'Val2'] })`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`combn` is a work-horse here, which can be used to generate unique pairwise combinations:

```
combn(as.character(dat$Name), 2, simplify=FALSE)
#[[1]]
#[1] "A" "B"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "A" "C"
#
#[[3]]
#[1] "B" "C"
```

You can also pass the results of these pairwise combinations to a function then:

```
# set.seed(1)
##for reproducibility

combn(
  as.character(dat$Name),
  2,
  FUN=function(x) do.call(`-`, dat[dat$Name == x[1], -1] / dat[dat$Name == x[2], -1])
)
#[1] -8.2526585  2.6940335  0.1818427

AB3
#[1] -8.252659
AC3
#[1] 2.694033
BC3
#[1] 0.1818427
```

Comment: Thanks, this is nice and accomplishes the first goal. Do you know of a way to approach the second part, using `dat2` and grouping by Region?

Answer (score 1):

With data.table, you can do it using the code below:

```
library(data.table)
dat <- data.table(Region = rep(LETTERS[24:26], each=3),
                   Name = rep(LETTERS[1:3], 3),
                   Val1 = rep(rnorm(3), 3),
                   Val2 = rep(rnorm(3), 3))
dat2 <- merge(dat, dat, by="Region", allow.cartesian = T)[Name.x < Name.y]
dat2[, Val1Ratio := Val1.x / Val1.y]
dat2[, Val2Ratio := Val2.x / Val2.y]
dat2[, Diff := Val1Ratio - Val2Ratio]
```

Answer (score 0):

@thelatemail's answer worked well on the first part of my question. I originally tried to add the below information as an add-on edit to their answer to address the second part of my question. This edit was rejected so I'm putting it here as an answer:

---

One way to use @thelatemail's answer to address the second part of the question (relating to dat2 and grouping by Region) is the following:

```
library("dplyr")
Regions <- unique(dat2$Region)
out <- data.frame(Region = Regions, AB3 = NA, AC3 = NA, BC3 = NA)
for (i in 1:length(Regions)){

  dat2temp <- dat2 %>% filter(Region==Regions[i])

  out[i,2:4] <-   combn(
    as.character(dat2temp$Name),
    2,
    FUN = function(x) do.call(`-`, dat2temp[dat2temp$Name == x[1], -(1:2)] / dat2temp[dat2temp$Name == x[2], -(1:2)])
    )
}

> out
#   Region       AB3        AC3       BC3
# 1      X -4.368693 -0.4772375 0.3004291
# 2      Y -4.368693 -0.4772375 0.3004291
# 3      Z -4.368693 -0.4772375 0.3004291
```

There are probably better solutions that avoid a for-loop, and I'd love to hear them. I expect there's a cleaner solution that uses dplyr::group_by or cut or similar.